# how to console different js file variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, screen

In short just imagen,
i have two screen such as screen1.js & screen2.js

screen1.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, RefreshControl, Text, SafeAreaView, Fragment } from 'react-native';


const TTrail = () =>{

const information = [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005];
  
}

export default TTrail;
```

so as you can see i have an array in screen1.js which is information.Now i want to console this information in another file which is screen2.js

screen2.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Dimensions, RefreshControl, Text, SafeAreaView, Fragment } from 'react-native';
import TTrail from './screen1';


const Trail = () =>{

console.log(information);
  
}

export default Trail;
```

**So, How can work this things successfully! i want to console.log(information) in screen2.js.**

anyone can help me to work it.
ThankYOU in advance for trying!!!

Answer (score 0):

U can pass the between from one screen to another screen by parama.
screen 01:
navigation.navigate('SecondPage', {
paramKey: userName,
})
Screen 02

route.params.paramKey